# Show a gramian matrix is positive definite (possible contradiction)

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

Given any real basis for the polynomials of degree n-1, $\{N_1(x), ..., N_n(x) \}$, and the inner product given by $\langle f,g\rangle = \int^1_0 f(t)g(t) \,  dt$, show that the matrix with elements $\langle N_i,N_j\rangle$ is positive definite.

What I have done is to decompose N into the outer product $AA^\top $ ,where A is the vector consisting of the basis functions, that is $A=\matrix{N_1\\\vdots \\N_n}$.

Then showing $x^\top AA^\top x > 0$ by using the norm.

However, I read somewhere that all matrices that are made from outer products have rank 1, and this would contradict N being positive definite, since it is singular.

Does this mean that the outer product does not equal the matrix, or is there another explanation to this apparent contradiction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is an inner product and $e_1,\ldots, e_n$ a basis, then the matrix $N_{ij}:=g(e_i,e_j)$ is positive definite, because for a nonzero vector $v=\sum_j x_j e_j$ represented via a row-vector $x=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$, you have
$$
x N x^T=\sum_{i,j} x_i g(e_i,e_j) x_j=\sum_{i} x_i g(e_i, \sum_j x_j e_j)=\sum_i x_i g(e_i, v)=g(v,v)>0.
$$

Formally, the product of your $A$ (as a column vector) and $A^T$ doesn't make sense, you seem to be mixing matrix multiplication and inner product multiplication. Note that your "matrix" $A$ doesn't consists of numbers.

Decomposing such $N$ into a product of *matrices* $A A^T$ is actually possible only if you already *know* that your $N$ is positive (semi-)definite and symmetric. Just a remark.

Not sure what you mean by "all matrices that are made from outer products have rank 1".